# How to read an image in Hard drive in Android NDK?

Tags: c++, file-io, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using Android NDK to make a simple app that draw an image. I run the app on my HTC M8 phone using Android 6.0. I use stb_image library (https://github.com/nothings/stb), which uses fopen to read the image . When I tried to load the image in my hard drive (It locates at "D:/Lighthouse.jpg"), I got the error because it couldn't open it with fopen, I'm sure the path to my image is correct. **My code works fine in Visual Studio but not in Android**. What am i doing wrong?

**Update**: I've searched around and add the following permission to my AndroidManifest.xml but it still doesn't work at all.

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" />
```

The error Log:

```
I/libgl2jni: Failed to load image: can't fopen
I/libgl2jni: Width =  = 1865550320
I/libgl2jni: Height =  = 1873207072
W/Adreno-ES20: <core_glTexImage2D:501>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
```

My image render class that call function loading image using fopen:

```
void generateTexture()
{

    glGenTextures(1 , &mTexture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mTexture);// Bind our 2D texture so that following set up will be applied

    //Set texture wrapping parameter
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);

    //Set texture Filtering parameter
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_NEAREST);

    //Load the image. This works fine in Visual Studio but not in Android Studio
    int picWidth,picHeight,n;
    unsigned char* image = stbi_load("D:/Lighthouse.jpg", &picWidth, &picHeight, &n,0);
    if (image == NULL ) {

        LOGI("Failed to load image: %s", stbi_failure_reason());

    }
    LOGI("Width =  = %d\n",
         picWidth);
    LOGI("Height =  = %d\n",
         picHeight);
    //Generate the image
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB , picWidth , picHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    stbi_image_free(image);// Free the reference to the image
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0); //Unbind 2D textures

}
```

Comment: Are you trying it in the emulator?

Comment: I'm sorry, forgot to provide this information. I run it on my HTC M8 phone.

Comment: So I do not understand - how can you access "D:/Lighthouse.jpg"? Does this path exist on your device, when the drive is connected?

Comment: This path doesn't exist on my phone. It locates in my D hard drive of my PC. Is it only possible to access file in Internal storage or SD card of the phone? Sorry for the dump question, I'm new to Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your Android devices you can only access the phone storage, you cannot access a file on your PC hard drive, at least not easily. Either put the file on the device storage, or a USB drive, or on a server.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I get it now. Btw, is it ok to put it in my SD card? If yes, how should i address it for the stbi_load function? Is stbi_load("/sdcard/Lighthouse.jpg", ....) correct ? The full path to my SD card is : Computer\HTC One_M8\SD card.

Comment: You can access files from storage, internal or external, no problem. I think the easiest way will be to call a Java method, that uses Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory

Comment: I use the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() to get the path. It returns :"/storage/emulated/0" . So I change input of the stbi_load("/storage/emulated/0/Lighthouse.jpg",....) . However, it still couldn't open the image, i'm pretty sure the image does exist there.

Comment: I suggest a practical approach to save time - in the java, where you get the path, create a file. Then, go check in your device where it was created, and then I believe you will be able to know how to access your file. This way you will avoid any further confusion.

Comment: I have done the search around and I think it's failed to load because I am using Android 6.0 and the permission must be accepted by user before it could run. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. General explanation here, if it helps: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: thanks for your advice. Btw, may i ask where should i place those function in? It would be great if you could guide me with a simple project showing how to use those function. Sorry for the dumb question again, I apologize if I'm bothering you too much.

Comment: I would put it in the main activity I guess. Take a look at this sample project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RuntimePermissions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135838/discussion-between-toan-tran-and-yakobom).